# Use the $\varepsilon - \delta$ definition of the limit to verify that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,5)} xy = 10$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

Use the $\varepsilon - \delta$ definition of the limit to verify that $\lim_{(2,5)\to(2,5)} xy = 10$. Hint: xy - 10 = (x-2)(y-5) + 5(x-2) + 2(y-5).

I’ve got as far as defining $\delta$ as $\frac{\varepsilon}{8}$ but can’t figure out how to formally prove it. Been stuck on it for days, could anyone shed some light? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\delta = \min(1,\frac{\epsilon}8 )$, hence we know that $\delta^2 \le \delta$.

\begin{align}
|xy-10| &\le |x-2||y-5| + 5|x-2| + 2|y-5|\\
&< \delta^2 + 5\delta + 2\delta \\
&\le 8\delta\\
&\le \epsilon
\end{align}

Comment: Do you not have to start at $\sqrt{(x-2)^2 + (y-5)^2} < \delta$ and get to $|xy - 10| < \varepsilon$ ?

Comment: of course, that is formal writing. Give it a try, the main steps are already here. Note that if $\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-5)^2}< \delta$, then we know that $|x-2|<\delta$.